# How do I create a Tabbar that has NavControllers that hold tableVCs inside?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I am creating my first iPhone application and I am stuck.

I want to have a tabbed view (with 3 tabs).

Each tab will have a list of articles for the user to view, and upon click the article will be shown.

My design as for now is:

1. Window
2. TabviewController
3. Each contains a NavController
4. Each nav controller contains a tabview controller (that displays the article titles)
5. A ditailed view is shown on table row tab.

The behavior of 3 to 5 is similar for all tabs.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: What are you stuck with?

Comment: yes is the right approach.Anyway I don't understand what is your problem, why you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sounds perfectly right.